# ReactJS search bar child to parent

Tags: reactjs, search, components

I have a search bar component which is viewed on all pages of a project. Is there a way that I can have the same search bar component but have a property that I could pass so that it knows which data to search through. My search component is `<SearchBar type="PASS THIS VALUE" />` and this is rendered:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  render () {


function handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Clicked!!!");
}
return (
<div className="row main-search">
  <div className="column">
    <form action="">
        <fieldset>
          <label htmlFor="search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Start typing..." id="search-box" />
          </label>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
  </div>
  <div className="column">
    <div className="float-right"><button className="add-new" onClick={handleClick}>Add New</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
  )
 }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

If this isn't possible is there a way that the searchBar can know which page the user is on and know which data to search through?

Update:
I am using a router element and the `searchBar` component is located inside parent App.js. I'm using the router like:

```
<SearchBar />
        <Route
          exact path="/" children={({ match, ...rest }) => (
            <TransitionGroup component={firstChild}>
              {match && <TourList {...rest} />}
            </TransitionGroup>
        )}/>
```

Comment: Are you using a router ? Can you share the parent component of `SearchBar` ?

Comment: I am using `react-router-dom` which is inside the main app.js file

Comment: You can either pass the router props to your `SearchBar` to be able to access the current route props or use a HOC like redux or mobx to handle a global app state to make communication between your components easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the props through `this.props` and set the value of `input` accordingly, but beware that the component will become controlled by react flow, you won't be able to change the input, thus you need `onChange` event handler for that and controlled local state version of that prop instead.

It may go like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  state = { // pass default value from "type" prop
    type: this.props.type
  };
  // making sure we don't call setState excessively
  // as per https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    
    if (nextProps.type !== this.props.type) {
      this.setState({ type: nextProps.type });
    }
  }
  
  // pulling out handleClick function from render()
  // to avoid creating it on every render call
  handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Clicked!!!");
  }
  
  // making sure we update our controlled component state
  // so we can actually type and get the change back in the value
  // more info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ type: e.target.value });
  };
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="row main-search">
        <div className="column">
          <form action="">
              <fieldset>
                <label htmlFor="search">
                  <input type="text" 
                    placeholder="Start typing..." 
                    id="search-box"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    // listening for our local and controlled version
                    // of "type" prop that is now reacting both to
                    // parent prop change and to local input change through typing
                    value={this.state.type}/>  
                </label>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div className="column">
          <div className="float-right">
            <button className="add-new" onClick={handleClick}>Add New</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: I believe this wouldn't work, how will the search component know which data to search from if there a 3 sets?

Comment: I am not sure I got your question. What does "if there a 3 sets?" mean?

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan I think the OP is asking for a way to pass props to his SearchBar instead of a way to handle props in it.

Comment: I have a single search component that will search through sets of data. The data it searches through will depend on what page the user is on. Rather than having a `SearchUserComponent` and a SearchMailComponent` I can just have a `SearchComponent` and pass in the page route to it.

Comment: Alright now I get you. In this case you don't need to pass the route into the component, you can have your component as normal <route path="/yourroute" component={Component} /> and inside component you can access the route options through props, like `this.props.match`